# calling cgi script from div and javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, cgi

I have a index.cgi which has a div like

```
<div id="AddCodeTab">
    <div id="CodeContainer" style="width: 100%;"></div>
</div>
```

So this div gets its content from `addcode.js`

I have another cgi page `databasecall.cgi`

So how do I define the `addcode.js` so that dropdown box in the div will get its value from another cgi page `databasecall.cgi`

Answer (score 2):

In your addcode.js include the following code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.ajax({url: "databasecall.cgi", success: function(result){
        $("#ajaxElement").html(result);    
    }});

});
```

And your index.cgi should have jQuery Library loaded. It should look something similar to this...

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Loading a CGI file via jQuery/AJAX</h1>
<!-- more content -->
<header id="pageHeader"><h2>This section is populated using jQuery/AJAX</h2>
<div id="ajaxElement"></div>
</header>
<!--more content -->    
<!-- absolute or relative path to your jQuery Library.  You can also use CDN from jQuery.org.  I use npm to install mine.   -->
<script src="/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- make sure your path to jQuery libray is correct -->
<script src="addcode.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have tis error: cam.html:1 Failed to load http://xxxxxxxx/anony/mjpg.cgi: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.